# Text to speech constructor crashing the app android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

In my app I am using fragments and viewpager. I have a separate text to speech class which extends Activity but doesn't have a layout. I have instantiated this class in FragmentAdapter class, which calls speaks function according to the activity currently on the screen. However the text to speech constructor is causing app to crash resulting in force close. I have figured out the culprit in text to speech constructor is the context, although I have used both getApplicationContext() and className.this but still it crashes the app. Here is the code:

```
public class textToSpeech extends Activity{

TextToSpeech tts=null;

public textToSpeech()
{
    Log.d("text to speech", "constructor");

    tts = new TextToSpeech(textToSpeech.this , new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            Log.d("text to speech", "init");

            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
            {
                Log.d("text to speech", "condition");

                tts.setPitch(1.1f); 

                tts.setSpeechRate(0.4f); 

                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Kindly guide me to solve this problem.

I have started text to speech activity using startActivity() , but still I am getting NullPointerException when I call the method in text to speech class. (I have instantiated text to speech class)

```
 tts.SpeakText("hello world"); // in fragmentPagerAdapter exception class
```

In text to speech class

```
public void SpeakText (String text)
{
    Log.d("text to speech", "speaking");

    if(text!=null)

            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is because you put your code in the activity constructor, but the activity is still not initialized. Move your code in `onCreate` and it should work :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    tts = new TextToSpeech(textToSpeech.this , new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            Log.d("text to speech", "init");
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

By the way, try to follow the conventions, classes in Java should start with an uppercase letter. It's also an activity, so you should add `Activity` at the end (`TextToSpeechActivity` would be a good name). I was a bit confused by looking at your code.

Comment: I instantiate above class in FragmentAdapter extended class. If I put the above code in onCreate, I would have to start the activity with startActivity, which I can't do in a non activity class.

Comment: So it extends from `Activity`, but it's not an activity? Extending from `Activity` just to get a context doesn't work if it isn't started with `startActivity()`. You have to rethink your design.

Comment: so what can I do? What I want is, when the fragment changes when the user swipes, textToSpeech speaks the text according to that fragment. For that I have created string array and passing a string to textTospeech class method mentioned above.

Comment: I have found the reason for force close. The oncreate method of textToSpeech class is not getting called even when though I am starting this activity with startActivity. I have defined this activity in manifest.xml and created its layout with 0dp height and width as well. What can be the problem now?